# how to create group of gwt Order list

Tags: gwt

Hi,

My goal is to create a list of items in GWT similar to how it is done in HTML using ordered and unorderd lists. Can someone explain to me how this can be achieved in GWT?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the way HTML represents lists 100%, or are you just trying to display some data in an organized way? [GWT Showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html) could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the dom API in com.google.gwt.dom.client which has a syntax very close from the JavaScript one:

```
for (String listItem : listData) {
    LIElement liElement = Document.get().createLIElement();
    liElement.setInnerText(step);
    this.olElement.appendChild(liElement);
}
```

this example simply add the list item build from the listData List end append them in the ordered list. I used UiBinder to get the olElement so you have to get a root element somewhere (Document has a method getElementById) and add your Element to it.